# XML schema for Offfice 2007

Tags: xml, ms-office, wordml

I need the xml template for Word 2007. In Word 2003 it starts like the following and continues. What I need is the generic template of Word 2007 in xml format which can be used as the base for WordML to xml transformations and viceversa. Someone experienced in WordML would definitely know what I am asking for! If someone knows please let me know. Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?> 
<w:wordDocument>xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml"..........."
```

Comment: This is not clear. Did you already try to unzip the docx file? (docx is just a zip file) That will give you the actual word file. Or are you after the schema for WordML. Try this as a starting point http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_XML_formats

Comment: Yes I need the schema for WordML. I need the schema for Word 2007. How can I have that? Can it be generated easily? Thanks.

Comment: In Word 2007 or later, create a new document, then "save as" .XML.  That will give you the "Flat OPC" XML it sounds like you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks Jason. I've tried that. It's the most approximate to what I am looking for. but it doesn't give the full thing. I want the full schema. :(

Comment: @JasonPlutext Jason I know you can help me.. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124) is the Open XML SDK

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/ee330855.aspx) is the msdn content on learning Open XML

To be complete [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=101) are the WordML  (Word 2003) Schema files.

Comment: thanks but I do not know how to use these. What would they give me once installed? I do not have much knowledge with this.

Comment: Based on your question this might be an answer. I added the Learn Open XML link as well. That will explain stuff and starts the learning.

Comment: thanks mate, I will look into that to see if that is there and let you know.