# WordML Schema generation

Tags: ms-word, wordml

I need the xml template for Word 2007. In Word 2003 it starts like the following and continues. What I need is the generic template of Word 2007 in xml format which can be used as the base for WordML to xml transformations and viceversa. Someone experienced in WordML would definitely know what I am asking for! If you have used docbook roundtripping, what I need is the template document which can be used for the "wordml.template" parameter. The template for Word 2003 is already there. I need the template for Word 2007. If someone knows please let me know how to have that. Thanks!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<?mso-application progid="Word.Document"?> 
<w:wordDocument>xmlns:w="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/word/2003/wordml"..........."
```

Comment: See my answer to your earlier question (which got closed): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776070/xml-schema-for-offfice-2007   There is a difference between a sample XML file which validates against a schema, and the schema itself.  I told you how to create a sample XML file, which, best I can tell, is what you are still asking for here.  Open the Word 2003 template in Word, then "save as" XML (Word 2007 XML).  That should do it.

Comment: @JasonPlutext you have told it half correct. :) I found what I needed by making a zip file out of the xml. Please add this as an answer so that I can mark it correct. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer to your earlier question (which got closed): [XML schema for Offfice 2007](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10776070/xml-schema-for-offfice-2007)

There is a difference between a sample XML file which validates against a schema, and the schema itself.

I told you how to create a sample XML file, which, best I can tell, is what you are still asking for here.

Open the Word 2003 template in Word, then "save as" XML (Word 2007 XML). That should do it.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one schema. You may be able to get them here:

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4463

Comment: thanks I had tried this and could not get what I need. Thanks for the support. :)